# Angular js : Dynamic expression not working for ng-switch-when

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I have a div based on switch but the switch has a boolean variable but the value will be evaluated based on the row.id. Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

```
  <div ng-switch="hasUrl">
    <a ng-switch-when="row.id.indexOf(':') < 0 === true" href="{{url + row.id}}">  <!-- hasUrl = true -->
    {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
    <a ng-switch-default href=".......">
      {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `===`, remove it.

```
<div ng-switch="hasUrl">
    <a ng-switch-when="row.id.indexOf(':') < 0" href="{{url + row.id}}">  <!-- hasUrl = true -->
        {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
    <a ng-switch-default href=".......">
       {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be
>   expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match
>   against. For example, ng-switch-when="someVal" will match against the
>   string "someVal" not against the value of the expression
>   $scope.someVal.

So according to the docs take following example to solve your case:

```
    <div ng-switch="hasUrl">
     <span ng-switch-when="row.id.indexOf(':') < 0"> WONT SHOW </span> <!-- WILL NOT WORK EVER -->
     <span ng-switch-when="makeItWork"> ALSO, WONT SHOW</span> 
     <span ng-switch-when="true">WILL NOT SHOW EITHER</span>
     <span ng-switch-when="1">WILL SHOW</span>
    </div>
```

Look carefullyat scope variables and their values:

```
$scope.hasUrl = 1; /*  NOTICE != true BUT 1*/
$scope.row = {};
$scope.row.id = "true:";
$scope.makeItWork = $scope.row.id.indexOf(':') > 0 ? 1 : 0;
console.log($scope.makeItWork); /* SEE THAT TRUE WILL BE LOGGED BUT IT STILL WONT SHOW */
```

So even though `ng-switch` will evaluate an expression, it seems `ng-switch-when` wont. If I were you I would just stick to `ng-if` instead.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lfrecia/ELurv/40/) Fixed fiddle